# Css floating problem (width:100%)

Tags: css

**HTML**

## Sorted it for seo

```
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="nav1">
  <ul>
  <li>nav 1</li>
  <li>nav 2</li>
  <li>nav 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>    
<div class="nav2">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav1 {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
.nav2 {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    background:#09F;
}
```

## the numbering:

**1: content**

**2: nav1**

**3: nav2**

**4: container**

I want something like that;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH5OR.jpg

But the result is bad.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypCft.jpg

Comment: Are you sure your images are the right way around there? Which is your desired result?

Comment: put `nav1` and `nav2` inside `content`.

Comment: @n0rd I moved, but remained above

Comment: @n0rd  [to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/VAAfX/) 
BUT, looks different in the browser [link](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/1929/ie8m.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnbz2/)

This will work as it is, providing the content will be higher than the menus. If that's not the case, then you can adjust the `min-height` value on `.content`. You should set it to the height of your highest menu.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br />Content<br /></div>

    <div class="nav1">
        <ul>
            <li>nav 1</li>
            <li>nav 2</li>
            <li>nav 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nav2">
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative
}
.nav1 {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ccc
}
.nav2 {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #ccc
}
.content {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    background: #09f;
    min-height: 200px
}
#footer {
    background: #999
}
```

Comment: I already addressed that. You should add a `min-height` to `.content`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mnbz2/2/ - I changed the `min-height` to `340px`. I know this isn't perfect, but it should be viable. Do you really have such a dynamic, changing menu that you can't just stick `min-height: 400px` or something? Also, how many pages will your highly SEO optimized site have with that little content? Content is the most important thing for SEO :)

Comment: This menu(nav1) is dynamic. There are sometimes 10, sometimes 30 items

these areas is variable: nav's, content, footer

Comment: You could fix it easily with a little jQuery, would that be acceptable?

Comment: I have no idea what you meant in that last comment.

Comment: @thirtydot  Thank you. I did with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

html: <div class="container">container</div>

css: .container {
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid;
    clear:both;
}

**example:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.nav1 {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid;
}
.nav2 {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    background:#09F;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid;
    clear:both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">Content</div>

<div class="nav1">
<ul>
<li>nav 1</li>
<li>nav 2</li>
<li>nav 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="nav2">
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container">container</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve your desired layout may be to wrap your nav divs into your content div. You're not getting the exact layout (the content div is not just in teh center but is spread to the whole width), but its a sollution as flexible as possible

```
  <div class="content">Content
    <div class="nav1">
      <ul>
      <li>nav 1</li>
      <li>nav 2</li>
      <li>nav 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
    <div class="nav2">
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```